# Message Sent to Deallocated instance on method dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, instruments, nszombies

I receive the following error while my UITableView is loading:

```
*** -[NSObject respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x23fa7cff0
```

I've used NSZombies to track down the error to the line:

```
SHFeedCell *cell = (SHFeedCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Where CellIdentifier has previously been declared:

```
CellIdentifier = [SHFeedCell getCellIdentifierForPost:currentPost];
```

I've included an image from instruments.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Log output:

```
2015-01-09 12:34:49.896 Shout[73650:6147424] -[SHFeedTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] line 478 $ cell identifier: feedCellImageDescription
2015-01-09 12:34:49.974 Shout[73650:6147424] -[SHFeedTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] line 481 $ cell: <SHFeedCell: 0x25150bc40; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 495); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x25151bfe0>>
2015-01-09 12:34:50.051 Shout[73650:6147424] *** -[NSObject respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x2514edff0
```

Comment: `[static NSString *CellIdentifier = [retrieve CellIdentifier dynamically` That is not code so what the heck is it?

Comment: And what on earth is the purpose of the image from Instruments? No one cares how much _time_ this takes; you need to be tracking down retains/releases.

Comment: Added more useful image and code

Comment: Prove, please, that the code `CellIdentifier = [SHFeedCell getCellIdentifierForPost:currentPost];` has actually run and provided a non-nil result _before_ the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` call.

Comment: Added log output showing that both cell identifier and cell are not nil

Comment: Are you sure this has anything to do with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`? I am a bit confused by that. The zombie problem is on a `respondsToSelector` call.

Comment: Per the first image I posted, NSZombie seems to have picked out 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier' as the problem line, but if you have any other ideas regarding where the 'respondsToSelector' issue is, I'd be happy to explore them.  Is there anyway I can get the object from the memory address?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the first image". I now see just one image, and it focuses on your scroll view delegate. You don't show enough of the stack trace for me to see what's going on, but maybe you can figure it out from there.

Comment: Is that not UITableview's internal scrollview?

Comment: Okay, good theory. But a zombie means that something has vanished behind the code's back, and now the code is trying to send a message to that vanished thing. What has vanished? Is it the table view's delegate?

Comment: Okay, so I found what's being deallocated, but I don't understand why...In `SHFeedCell`, I have a `scrollView` that's connected through `IBOutlet`.  Unfortunately, when `-(void)awakeFromNib` is called, the `scrollView` is `null`, which is odd seeing as it was defined in a `Nib`.  It's not deallocated immediately, but only after a couple of iterations. Any thoughts?

Comment: Wow, you've made huge progress on this! - Can you say more about how the nib loads, how it is set up, how the scroll view is configured? And does it have a delegate? (I'm still wondering if it is the delegate, not the scroll view, that is missing in action.)

Comment: As of now, I think I solved it.  the `self.scrollView.delegate = self` had been set in an `SHFeedCell` method as opposed to `SHFeedCell`'s `awakeFromNib` method.

Comment: Excellent! Well done.